# How was this clone created?

Tags: jupiters-legacy

Near the end of the first season, we find out that

> Walter

seemingly created the clone of Blackstar.

Since Skyfox seems to have some sort of power to create super-technology, it would make sense if he had created the clone. However, aside from flight, strength, and durability, Walter's only powers seem to be telepathic. Further, Blackstar's major abilities seem to come from a rare antimatter core, which cannot be easy to reproduce; if it were, not only would more villains be using it to be as powerful as Blackstar, but the Union would have used something similar when reviving the clone (the lack of a suitable power source was specifically mentioned as an obstacle).

To cap it off, everyone seems to take for granted that only Skyfox had the technology to have created the sphere that was inside the Blackstar clone. If this was something that even  Walter could have managed, why would they be so confident?

In short, how did he create the clone?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because he had the plans on how to make the anti-matter device from Blackstar's notes?

The Union had captured Blackstar. Presumably they also secured his lab/lair where he created the antimatter core.  Using that information, any of the current senior Union members might be able to replicate what Blackstar did and incorporate that into the cloned Blackstar. As a further possibility, the Union members might also have access to memory recordings from Blackstar being held in SuperMax allowing at least a basic level of clone 'consciousness'/awareness of the Union.  Enough to allow it to know how to fight and how to use the antimatter core.

The reason the Union members believed Skyfox as the likely creator is that ***without*** Blackstar's notes Skyfox would be the only person that could recreate the antimatter core.  They hadn't considered:

> one of their own, Walter, was the actual creator using Blackstar's notes/information.